# java script error in if else statement

Tags: javascript, syntax-error

```
var manu = "Hallo";
if (manu === "Hallo"); {
console.log("It Works Bro")
}
else {

console.log("Nope Sir")

}
```

GETTING THIS ERROR:

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token else

Comment: you don't need semicolon after if;

Comment: The `;` decouples the `if(..)` from the following *block* (`{..}`), therefore the `else` does not follow an if block anymore, but just a regular block, therefore it fails

Answer (score 3):

Remvoe `;` from the end of `if (manu === "Hallo");`

```js
var manu = "Hallo";

if (manu === "Hallo") { // <- No need of `;`
   console.log("It Works Bro");
} else {
   console.log("Nope Sir");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have a redundant (read: wrong) semicolon (`;`) after the `if`'s closing parenthesis, and are missing semicolons in the statements in both the `if` and the `else`'s bodies:

```
var manu = "Hallo";
if (manu === "Hallo") { // ; Remove here
    console.log("It Works Bro"); // And added here
}
else {
    console.log("Nope Sir"); // And here
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It's because of putting semicolon after if condition.
Just remove that